# Updating a val in scala by reassigning

Tags: scala, immutability, scala-collections

I am trying to update the value stored in a val in scala. I know i can't just directly do this like this: `val x = 2; x = 1`. This is not what I am doing, as I know you cannot reassign to a val. This is what I am trying to do:

```
    val fp = List((1,2));
    val fp = fp ::: List((1,3)); //hoping that x is List((1,2),(1,3))
```

But I get an message saying:

```
 error: recursive value fp needs type
```

Also note, that I am restricted to using immutable data structures and vals only.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Use a var instead?

Comment: As I said, I am limited to immutable data structures. Var is mutable.

Comment: I'm limited to vals and immutable data structures

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Essentially, you're saying "I want to mutate immutable data."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reassign val in Scala. You should either use var:

```
var fp = List((1,2))
fp = fp ::: List((1,3))
```

Or use two vals:

```
val fp = List((1,2))
val fp2 = fp ::: List((1,3))
```

Usually you should try to avoid using vars, if you can. It makes your programs cleaner, and this way is surely more functional. So, I would prefer second option with two vals.

By the way, note, that you don't need to use semicolons. In fact, their usage in Scala is kind of discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, we encourage you to *not* reassign, as it creates undesirable side effects throughout your code, and makes it harder to reason about.

You need to get in the habit of throwing away variables and their mutations and starting to consider *bindings* of expressions. `Var` is considered bad form in Scala. As is reassignment. The following does exactly what you want, without any of the unwanted side effects `var`s and mutation would create:

```
val x = 2; val y = 1
```

If you needed to "mutate" `x`, then you could do something like the following:

```
val x = 2
val y = x + 2 // x = 2, y = 4
```

So that what you wanted from th `fp` would look like this:

```
val fp = List((1,2));
val fp1 = fp ::: List((1,3));
```